# Disable artifact publishing if build fails in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

My build scenario is like this (simplified):

1. Compile
2. Package (*.zip)
3. Deploy to test environment
4. Run tests over the environment

If tests fail TeamCity still publishes artifacts. This is unnecessary and consumes disk space. How can i prevent this? Can't find any check box or something (TeamCity 6.5 Enterprise).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, TeamCity doesn't have a built-in option to disable artifact publishing if the build fails.

However, in the build script called by TeamCity you could try:

1. Removing artifact paths from the build configuration, and instead emitting the appropriate [TeamCity service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-artPublishing) with your artifact paths only when tests are complete and successful.
2. Only copying files to the artifact paths configured in TeamCity *after* the tests are complete and successful.